# Поиск по списку

Tags: jquery, html

Всем привет.

У меня вот такая вот проблема. Имеется меню:

```
<ul id="menu">
     <li id="1">Ссылка1<span class="list1">[<span id="list1">0</span>]</span></li>
     <li id="2">Cсылка2<span class="list1">[<span id="list2">0</span>]</span></li>
     <li id="3">Ссылка3<span class="list1">[<span id="list3">0</span>]</span></li>
     <li id="4">Ссылка4<span class="list1">[<span id="list4">0</span>]</span></li>
     <li id="5">Ссылка5<span class="list1">[<span id="list5">0</span>]</span></li>
</ul>
```

Не подскажите, как осуществить сверку нажатого пункта меню со всеми? Если такой находится, то присвоить ему определенное значение.

```
     $('li').click(function() { 
         var current = $(this);      // текущая позиция
         var id = current.attr('id');   // текущий id
         var str = "#list"+ id;
     var number = parseInt($(str).text());  // изменение индекса
```

Вот как осуществить поиск по всему списку? Если текущая (нажатая) `id` совпадает с каким-либо из меню, то выполнить определенные действия.

Comment: я думаю, надо создать массив id и сравнить нажатый пункт с элементами массива, если встретилось совпадение - выполняем действия.

Comment: Если не сложно - поясните что должно произойти с HTML-ем после нажатия, а то не совсем понятно.

Comment: Вот что должна делать меню.<br>
1. При клике на ссылку все остальные сдвигаются в сторону.<br>
2. При клике на другую ссылку сначала все возвращаются на исходную позицию, а затем сдвигаются относительно текущей, как в п. 1.<br>
3. После клика на ссылке в ее текст добавляется в конец счетчик кликов (например, «Ссылка [2]»), а при каждом клике значение счетчика увеличивается. До первого клика ссылка счетчика не имеет («Ссылка»).<br>
4. После достижения порогового значения счетчика кликов (5) ссылка исчезает из списка.

Answer (score 1):

[Отфильтруйте](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) ваш набор DOM-элементов, если длина получится больше единицы, значит есть повторения:

```
...
var id = current.attr('id');//ваш индекс
if($('li').filter(function(index){
        return $(this).attr('id')==id;//можно проще
}).length > 1) //проверяем сколько li-шек с "вашим индексом" в списке
{
    //выполнить определенные действия
}
...
```

Comment: var id = current.attr('id');//индекс <br>
$(this).css('margin-left','0');  //для текущего значения<br>
if(id == 1)//когда выбрана 1я ссылка <br>
{ while (i<5){//проход до конца списка<br>                     
    current.next().animate({marginLeft:'20px'},{duration:200});<br>
    current = current.next()<br>
    if (i == 5); <br>
    i++;<br>
}}<br>
Не то получается приходится для каждого случая прописывать.<br>
Подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить:  <br>
При клике на другую ссылку сначала все возвращаются на исходную позицию, а затем сдвигаются относительно текущей, как в п.1
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать следующее <br>
1) Взять текущий на который нажали<br>
2) с помощью .next() найти его соседа который ниже, сдвигаешь его<br>
3) так делаешь в цикле while сдвигая всех его соседей снизу пока они там не кончаться<br>
4) аналогично с соседями сверху с помощью .prev()<br>
 Как это реализовать.

Comment: if (number <5){<br>
$(str).html(number); 
$(this).find('span.list1').show()<br>
$('li').each(function(){$(this).css('margin-left','0px');});<br>
while (current.next().length != 0){<br>                     current.next().animate({marginLeft:'20px'},{duration:200});<br>
current = current.next();}<br>
while (current1.prev().length != 0 ){ <br>                     current1.prev().animate({marginLeft:'20px'},{duration:200});<br>
current1 = current1.prev();}}<br>
else{ $(this).remove(); }});<br>